# Multiple site bindings on a single site in IIS

Tags: iis, binding, dns, subdomain

I don't know if the title of the question makes sense, but I'll try and explain the question below.

We have a single application, that will host a collection of sites in the following manner:

1. http://www.parentcompanysite.com

we want to create sub-sites for each of the company's child offerings, as such:

1. http://www.parentofferinga.com
2. http://www.parentofferingb.com
3. http://www.parentofferingc.com

All three of these offerings point to the exact same code base, hosted in IIS on port 80 (http://www.parentcompanysite.com).

We've got this working in our development environment by attaching host entries for each of the three offerings, but in production, this does not seem to work.

From my experience, this is a rather simple problem with a logical (HOSTS) solution. Is there something I'm missing?

Do I really need to register each of these as sub-domains, and then in the HOSTS file, point to the IP address binding currently being used by the root web site?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's serverfault.com question. IMHO.

Comment: Okay, how do I move it there?

Comment: @JadedEric You'd just flag your own question for a Moderator to move it for you. However, questions can only be migrated within 60 days. At this point I recommend you just copy/paste and delete from here.